# Numbers in reporting one way ANOVA

Tags: anova, degrees-of-freedom, notation, reporting

In reporting data for a one way ANOVA what do all the numbers in the following stand for?   $F (1, 24) = 44.4$,  $p < .01$.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Do you really have no idea what a p-value is?

Comment: I just need to confirm what the second number in parenthesis stands for, finishing a research paper under stress

Comment: I found this discussion helpful: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/book/export/html/213

Answer (score 2):

$F(1,24)=44.4$ codifies the inside the parenthesis the degrees of freedom:

$F(\color{red}{\text{df between groups}},\color{blue}{\text{df within groups}}) = \text{F-value (or F-ratio)}$ with

$\color{red}{\text{df between groups}}= \text{no. of groups}-1$

and

$\color{blue}{\text{df within groups}}=\text{subjects - no. groups}$

These are the values necessary to find the p-value.

Comment: Just to be clear, `subjects` (for within groups df) is just N, the total number of observations in the calculation. So within group df is N-k.  (Someone might come here and be confused because they may have 3000 observations on one subject :) : in that case N = 3000, not 1).